# What is this indicator underneath the cursor in Firefox?

Tags: css, macos, user-interface, firefox

I'm testing something in Firefox and noticed that it displays a teardrop-like indicator underneath the cursor of a `contenteditable`. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

It looks like the text selection control you see on iOS/Android devices, except I'm using macOS 10.14.6 and Firefox 72.0.

What is this thing called? What is it for on desktop? Is it for accessibility? Can it be styled, removed?

Comment: It appears to be a bug? It appears when you switch to Responsive Design Mode, and the back to regular mode. If you refresh, it goes away. Perhaps it's only meant to appear in Responsive Design Mode to emulate a mobile device?

Comment: I filed this bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1613957